# devtools manual build with ASCII titles

Tags: r, encoding, package, pdf-generation, devtools

I'm building a package but the documentation must be in Spanish, including the tilde character (i.e. í, é).

I have a simple function like this in an R file:

```
#' Función con acénto
#'
#' Permite instalar rápidamente de manera local un paquete previamente descargado
#' @param direccion La dirección del archivo local, poner .zip
#' @keywords FAhorroDS
#' @export
#' @encoding UTF-8
#' @author Eduardo Flores
#' @examples
#' FA_InstalarLocal("paquete_x_1.10.zip")

FA_InstalarLocal<-function(direccion)
{
  install.packages(direccion, repos = NULL, type="source")
}
```

And building the Rd via `devtools::document()`. The Rd file in man generated seems fine:

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/test.R
\encoding{UTF-8}
\name{FA_InstalarLocal}
\alias{FA_InstalarLocal}
\title{Función con acénto}
\usage{
FA_InstalarLocal(direccion)
}
\arguments{
\item{direccion}{La dirección del archivo local, poner .zip}
}
\description{
Permite instalar rápidamente de manera local un paquete previamente descargado
}
\examples{
FA_InstalarLocal("paquete_x_1.10.zip")
}
\author{
Eduardo Flores
}
\keyword{FAhorroDS}
```

However even if i'm specifying the encoding both here and in the DOCUMENTATION file, when I run: `system("R CMD Rd2pdf . --output=manual.pdf --force")`, I get the following error:

```
Hmm ... looks like a package
Converting Rd files to LaTeX Warning: ./man/FA_InstalarLocal.Rd:6: Some input could not be re-encoded to ASCII
```

When I see the package, the description is okay, but the title of the function turns out as NA.

[image]

Any ideas as to why everything else (the description has a tilde) is being correctly encoded but **not** the title?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Mexico.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Mexico.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Mexico.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Mexico.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] fahorro_0.1     devtools_1.10.0 magrittr_1.5    readxl_0.1.0    dplyr_0.4.3    
[6] FAhorroDS_1.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.6    roxygen2_5.0.1 R6_2.1.2       xlsx_0.5.7     stringr_1.0.0 
 [6] plyr_1.8.3     tools_3.2.4    parallel_3.2.4 DBI_0.3.1      withr_1.0.0   
[11] assertthat_0.1 digest_0.6.9   rJava_0.9-8    RODBC_1.3-12   xlsxjars_0.6.1
[16] memoise_1.0.0  stringi_1.0-1  SOAR_0.99-11
```

Comment: Did you set encoding in the DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: @Thomas yes I did, to UTF-8 as well